# Tools To Manage (Split, Edit More Easily, etc) Change Sets?

Tags: administration, metadata, change-set

I am not finding anything on AppExchange.

**Does anyone know of a "Change Set" editor better than that built into Salesforce?**   Trying to remove items from a change set is a nightmare.  We have a need to split up a change set that has "all" items needed into 4-5 smaller change sets.

Comment: Have you thought about using continuous integration tools as opposed to change sets? For example Flosum, or Copado? We've been using Flosum and it's real easy to bundle up specific changes into a package and then deploy them to any org Sandbox or Production. It's way way easier to manage than change sets.

Comment: Never heard of them.  I will check them out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not aware of any change set editing tools, there are definitely tools out there that can help with Salesforce deployments. In fact, if possible, I would avoid using Salesforce Change Sets altogether. They do not comply with the deployment best practices of modern software development. There is no risk analysis, a lack of visibility into the changes being rolled out for release, no insights into the business impact and associated vulnerabilities, etc. This blog post covers these and other shortcomings encountered by Salesforce experts when implementing change sets.

Few devs/admins in the Salesforce industry are aware of tools that can help with Salesforce deployments. But they do exist. There are cloud-based Jenkins Solutions and various software vendor apps such as Gearset that help with Salesforce deployments. And even fewer know of risk mitigation and risk planning, which can be achieved via software such as Panaya’s Release Dynamix for Salesforce.

*Full Disclosure: I work for Panaya